# Display image when hover over button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is [my site](http://classichits.ie/).

What I am trying to do: **display an image when user hovers over the links**.

I am definitely making some stupid mistake but I am not really sure which.

This is what I have done:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nm">
    <li><a href="#">Cork</a>
        <div class="place-image">
          <img src="http://classichits.ie/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/cork.png">
        </div>
    </li>

  .......Remaining  li's.....
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.place-image{
    display:none;
}

div.place-image{
    width:326px;
    height:326px;  
}
```

**javascript**

```
$('.place-image').hover(
    function() {
        $('.place-image').fadeIn('slow');
    },function() {
        $('.place-image').fadeOut('slow');
    }
);
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Not the problem, but why does your CSS have two entries for the same class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where tying to hover a hidden element. That is why your code was not working. You cannot trigger an event on a hidden element.

```js
$('a').hover(
    function() {
        $('.place-image').fadeIn('slow');
    },function() {
        $('.place-image').fadeOut('slow');
    }
);
```

```css
.place-image{
    display:none;
}

div.place-image{
width:326px;
height:326px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a href="#">Cork</a>
  <div class="place-image"><img src="http://classichits.ie/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/cork.png"></div>
</li>
```

Comment: thanks for replying.

But, uploadpie.com/ehCC2 this is what is happening. 

may be if you check my site, you might be able to figure out. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `hover` event to `li` like following.

```
$('li').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('.place-image').fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.place-image').fadeOut('slow');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I am trying to do display an image when hover over the links.

make it

```
<li>
  <a href="#">Cork</a>
  <div class="place-image"><img src="http://classichits.ie/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/cork.png"></div>
</li>


$('li a').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).next('.place-image img').fadeIn('slow');
    },function() {
        $(this).next('.place-image img').fadeOut('slow');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change your **Javascript**:(In your website `ul` has class `nm` use it to target specific `li` in `ul`. )

**HTML**

```
<li>
  <a href="#">Cork</a>
  <div class="place-image"><img src="http://classichits.ie/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/cork.png"></div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.place-image{
    display:none;
}

div.place-image{
width:326px;
height:326px;  
}
```

**javascript**

```
$( "ul.nm > li" ).
   $('li').hover(
      function() {
          $(this).find('.place-image').fadeIn('slow');
        }, function() {
          $(this).find('.place-image').fadeOut('slow');
    });
```

Comment: in your project where are you writing javascript code. filename.

Comment: its in a custom js file.
actually its wordpress site.  like this http://uploadpie.com/Me6Jc

Answer (score 0):

Issue: you cannot detect a `:hover` state on an element with `display: none`

A possible solution might be to hide only the img itself, and listen to the `:hover` on the wrapper `.place-image` or on the `a` or `li` as you wish. See the demo below:

```js
$('.place-image').hover(
    function() {
        $('img', this).fadeIn('slow');
    },function() {
        $('img', this).fadeOut('slow');
    }
);
```

```css
.place-image{
    width:326px;
    height:326px;  
}

.place-image img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a href="#">Cork</a>
  <div class="place-image">
    <img src="http://classichits.ie/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/cork.png">
   </div>
</li>
```

## Alternative solution

Depending on your circumstances you could achieve this also without js:

```css
.place-image {
    width:326px;
    height:326px;  
}

img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .4s ease;
  /*TODO: add crossbrowser prefixes*/
}

li:hover img{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
  <a href="#">Cork</a>
  <div class="place-image">
    <img src="http://classichits.ie/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/cork.png">
   </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for replying. thats exactly what I am trying to do. 

But, http://uploadpie.com/ehCC2 this is what is happening.

Comment: still same problem as in the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a').hover(
    function() {
        $('.place-image').fadeIn('slow');
    },function() {
        $('.place-image').fadeOut('slow');
    }
);
```

```css
.place-image{
    display:none;
}

div.place-image{
width:326px;
height:326px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a href="#">Cork</a>
  <div class="place-image"><img src="http://classichits.ie/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/cork.png"></div>
</li>
```