# Display image when hover button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm creating a set of questions where the user must choose.
I won't be providing a big image but rather I want to display a small image when hovered.

Sample how it displays (just on the right side when hovered)
[image: Hover Image Sample]

Here's my code so far only in HTML:

```html
<label class="btn buying-selling" style="outline-style: solid; outline-color: #fff6e5;"> 
<br> <input type="radio" id="flavor1" name="cake_flavor"/>
<span class="radio-chosen"></span><span class="buying-selling-word"> Orange </span> <div class="orangefla"> Im trying to display it here </div>

<label class="btn buying-selling" style="outline-style: solid; outline-color: #fff6e5;"> 
 <br> <input type="radio" id="flavor2" name="cake_flavor"/>
 <span class="radio-chosen"></span><span class="buying-selling-word"> Chocolate </span>

<label class="btn buying-selling" style="outline-style: solid; outline-color: #fff6e5;"> 
<br> <input type="radio" id="flavor3" name="cake_flavor"/>
<span class="radio-chosen"></span><span class="buying-selling-word"> Caramel </span> </label>
```

I have no idea how to start with the jquery for hovering.
Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: when hovered what?

Comment: @Banzay It might be "selected"... e-e... a label.

Comment: @Banzay something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552559/display-image-when-hover-over-button

Answer (score 1):

### I have added Test image

```js
   
$(function() {
$('span').each(function() {
$(this).mouseenter(function() {
  $('.orangefla').html('<img src=" http://www.learningspy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Testing_in_Progress.gif" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">');
});
$(this).mouseleave(function() {
  $('.orangefla').html('');
});
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="btn buying-selling" style="outline-style: solid; outline-color: #fff6e5;"> 
<br> <input type="radio" id="flavor1" name="cake_flavor"/>
<span class="radio-chosen"></span><span class="buying-selling-word"> Orange </span> <div class="orangefla"> Im trying to display it here </div>

<label class="btn buying-selling" style="outline-style: solid; outline-color: #fff6e5;"> 
 <br> <input type="radio" id="flavor2" name="cake_flavor"/>
 <span class="radio-chosen"></span><span class="buying-selling-word"> Chocolate </span>

<label class="btn buying-selling" style="outline-style: solid; outline-color: #fff6e5;"> 
<br> <input type="radio" id="flavor3" name="cake_flavor"/>
<span class="radio-chosen"></span><span class="buying-selling-word"> Caramel </span> </label>
```

**On Click JQuery Code is :-**

```
$(function() {
    $("#flavor1").click(function() {
     $('.orangefla').html('<img src=" http://www.learningspy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Testing_in_Progress.gif" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">');
    });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I see you've updated it. The first thing you did was exactly what I've wanted (I just need to adjust it on the right side). If possible the other buttons won't moved as well.

Answer (score 0):

with using JQuery you can use .hover() and .toggleClass() functions, code:

```
<script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  $(".buying-selling-word").hover(function() {
    $('.orangefla').toggleClass('mouseover');
  });
</script>

<style>
  .mouseover {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x150');
    border: 0;
  }
</style>

<label class="btn buying-selling" style="outline-style: solid; outline-color: #fff6e5;"> 
<br><input type="radio" id="flavor1" name="cake_flavor"/>
<span class="radio-chosen"></span><span class="buying-selling-word"> Orange </span>
<div class="orangefla"> Im trying to display it here </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/35a4L99j/